# Is it possible to revert x-axe values in line chart with chart.js

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I am using `chart.js` and i have `line chart` with values `from 10 to 100`.
My top point have value 100, but that is incorrect for my data. For me 100 is the bad result. Is there a way to `revert x-axe to start from 100 to 10`.

If its not possible, can someone recommend javascript **(NO jQuery)** chart, that can resolve my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in your chart options :

```
scaleOverride: true,   
scaleSteps: 10,
scaleStartValue: 100,
scaleStepWidth: -10
```

it shoud just do the trick.

See [a jsfiddle of it here](http://jsfiddle.net/rdtome/r2219x0e/).